# Azure Log Search Alerts - How to configure emails to show top 10 results

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

No doubt I will lose more points for asking the wrong question or something but I'm a bit stuck on an Azure Log Alerts issue.

For one application we have an email log search alert setup with a query which sends an email to a group any time we get an exception.

We have a seemingly identical one for another application but the key difference is one sends the **top 10 results in the email** and the other one doesn't. How can I configure my application such that I don't need to open up Azure Portal in order to see the log details?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I configure my application such that I don't need to open up Azure Portal in order to see the log details?

`Azure Log Analytics` alerts don't inherently include detailed log data in email notifications.

However, you can work around this limitation by using **Azure Logic Apps**.

Create a new `Logic App` in the `Azure Portal` by following the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/quickstart-create-example-consumption-workflow).

Add a trigger for `When a HTTP request is received` This will be your trigger point. follow the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-reqres?tabs=consumption#add-a-request-trigger) to create HTTP trigger in `Logic App`

Add a step to run your `Log Analytics` query using the **"HTTP"** action or the `Azure Log Analytics` connector.

[image]

Add a step to format the email using the **"Send an email"** action, in the email body, include the results from the **Log Analytics** query, Follow the [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/tutorial-process-email-attachments-workflow) for more details.

[image]

This way, when an alert is triggered, `Logic App` will run the query and send an email with the top 10 results with details in **CSV** file as below.

[image]

Comment: This is a possible solution but when you say they don't include log detail in the emails you have misread my question as one of my applications already includes this

Comment: Does Log Analytics show the application log details with data?

Comment: Yes if I click the link in the email and run the query I can see the details but that's pretty slow looking through say 10 emails