# Azure Alert Add More Informations

Tags: azure, azure-alerts

I am working on Azure alert configuration where I am getting only limited informations over Alert Email but I want to include more informations from query result like Error Code, Error Message etc.

How can I achieve this request?

For example:
Query:
exceptions
| where problemId != 'ClientConnectionFailure at forward-request'
| extend timestamp = column_ifexists('timestamp', datetime(2024-01-13T22:20:18.0000000Z))

Return details with error code and message

And to trigger alert I have added count function as below:

exceptions
| where problemId != 'ClientConnectionFailure at forward-request'
| summarize count() by type
| extend timestamp = column_ifexists('timestamp', datetime(2024-01-13T22:20:18.0000000Z))
| summarize AggregatedValue = sum(count_) by bin_at(timestamp, 10m, datetime(2024-01-13T22:30:18.0000000Z))

And condition is if its greater than 10

So is there any method to include error code and message mentioned under detail as I described in last message to alert email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am working on Azure alert configuration where I am getting only limited informations over Alert Email but I want to include more informations from query result like Error Code, Error Message etc.
> How can I achieve this request?

To include more information in an **email alert**, you can use **Azure Logic App** by following the steps below

1. Setup `Azure Logic App` in the `Azure Portal` by following the steps in [Ms Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/quickstart-create-example-consumption-workflow).

[image]

2. Create an `HTTP request` in `Azure Logic App` by following the steps in [Ms doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-reqres?tabs=consumption#add-a-request-trigger)
3. Add the **"Send an email"** action, in the email body, include the results from the **Azure Log Analytics** query, Follow the [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/tutorial-process-email-attachments-workflow) for more details.

**Reference:** Follow the [Stack Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77522641/azure-log-search-alerts-how-to-configure-emails-to-show-top-10-results/77527717#77527717), where I provided an answer for the related issue

[Customize alert notifications by using Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-logic-apps?tabs=send-email)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution but do we have any other alternatives as in my company they are not ready to implement Logic App due to high pricing.

Comment: As there is no alternative way to create an alert to include more information's in the alert.